# Spring returned page is empty

Tags: spring

I requested a page which was supposed to be populated with objects for a user, but the returned page was empty.

The controller for the request

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/main/user/testing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRecords(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, ModelMap 

        model) {
     if(userId !=null)

     {
           UserEntity user = userService.getUserByID(userId);

         model.addAttribute("setter", user);
     }

  return "/main/user/testing";
 }
```

The model for the parent and the associated children that is to be retrieved

UserEntity

```
   public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

        @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
        private UserEntity checker;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<UserEntity> setters = new HashSet<UserEntity>();

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="setter")
        private Set<Module> sModule = new HashSet<Module>();

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="checker")
        private Set<Module> cModule = new HashSet<Module>();
```

Module

```
    public class Module implements Serializable{

  @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "module_id")
      private Integer moduleId;

  @Column(name = "module_code")
      private String moduleCode;

  @Column(name = "module_name")
      private String moduleName;
```

So when at the controller I use the user id as the parameter I want it to return with the modules associated with the user.

The page itself is returned but all it has is the table headers ad no values from the database.

Requested page

```
   <table>
        <tr>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
            <th>Module Code</th>
            <th>Module Name</th>
              </tr>

       <c:forEach items="${setter}" var="obj" >
        <c:forEach items="${obj.sModule}" var="module" >


            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${obj.userId}" escapeXml="true" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${obj.name}" escapeXml="true" /></td>

                <td><c:out value="${module.moduleCode}" escapeXml="true" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${module.moduleName}" escapeXml="true" /></td>



            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: checking logs would go a long way. You can try to put the breakpoint on the `model.addAttribute("setter", user);` line and inspect the `user` value. That way you'd make sure if the problem is in the way data is accessed or in the way it's rendered.

Comment: I have used the breakpoint and debugged the code. After inspecting the value, the persistent set that I want to retrieve has no value. The other user details are accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Does the c:foreach work on a single object? You are returning exactly one user. Either get rid of the loop in your template or wrap the user entity in a list and put that list into the setter variable.

Comment: I tried to put the user entity in an array list but that did not work. I have also removed the loop. Is there another way the template can retrieve single object.